# Bootstrap Calendar I need group events similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I need one help to group similar events in array on JavaScript.

Object Main.

```
Object {  month_name: "Janeiro",events: Array[6] }
```

Events Array

```
Object { id: "3",class: "event-success"} 
Object { id: "5", class: "event-inverse" } 
Object { id: "8",class: "event-success"}
```

I need group similar class I need my array

```
Object { count : 2,class: "event-success"} 
Object { count: 1 ,class: "event-inverse"}
```

My code

```
$.each(t, function(k, v) {
    if (k == 'events') {
        $.each(v, function(x, a) {});
    }
});
```